# liquibase maven plugin disable checksum

Tags: maven-3, liquibase

I'm using liquibase with `maven-3`. The first run works as expected. Consecutive runs though (even if the sql files contain changes) fail, as they are viewed as equivalent from liquibase and ignored (checksum).

All the sql actions in my sql scripts have taken into account the previous runs, so I don't want this behaviour. With this setup that you see below, how can I force liquibase to **always** execute my scripts, no matter the changes?

As you can see below I've already tried setting `clearCheckSums` as a goal and indeed it clears the hash values, but still no luck (thus commented out).
This is the profile I've created

```
<profile>
    <id>liquibase-executions</id>
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>process-resources</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgres.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update-schema</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                            <!--<goal>clearCheckSums</goal>-->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.url}</url>
                            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                            <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase.sql</changeLogFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>update-data</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                            <!--<goal>clearCheckSums</goal>-->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                            <url>jdbc:postgresql://${db.url}</url>
                            <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                            <changeLogFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/liquibase-populate.sql</changeLogFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

And this is how I execute it

```
mvn process-resources -Pliquibase-executions -Ddb.url=POSTGRES_IP:5432/POSTGRES_DB -Dliquibase.username=POSTGRES_USERNAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Liquibase Maven plugin [expects](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/update-mojo.html#changeLogFile) a [changelog file](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html), no plain `.sql` file. This file should contain your `changeSets` that you want Liquibase to execute. These changeSets can be instructed to be run every time you run Liquibase (by default they're only executed once). So there's no need to tamper with the checksum. For example your changelog file could look something like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="your-id" author="msp" runAlways="true">
    ...
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The important part to achieve your intended behaviour is to set the `runAlways="true"` attribute in your liquibase changeset.

Comment: I don't use `changeSet` anywhere in my setup. All I'm using is `changeLogFile`. Is it possible to provide a solution based on the setup provided in my post? If I have to introduce `changeSet` in order to use this attribute, what is the complete end result?

Comment: No `changeSet`? Liquibase parses the databaseChangeLog tag in your `changeLogFile`, checks preconditions and if none fail executes the changeSets. IMHO that's the integral part of Liquibase and I think you're using it the wrong way.

Comment: No argument there. It's the first time I'm using this plugin so I'm trying to get the gist of it. Can you provide a solution incorporating `changeSet` (with the above setup in mind) and move your comment in your post for future reference?

Comment: Sure. Did just that. Hope that helps. Best check the quickstart http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart.html

Comment: Ok I made the changes and it works like a charm. Thanks for the help. Have fun